# Populate Table From Radio Button

Tags: php, ajax

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I've put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/getuserform.html) page from a tutorial found at 'w3schools' which populates a table with user details following selection of their name from a drop down list.

I'd now like to change this a little, and instead of the names being selected from a drop dowm menu, I'd like to have a list of the names on my form with a radio button against each. Then once the radio button is selected, the correct user details are shown in the table.

I've done quite a bit of research to try and find an example for this but without any success.

I just wondered whether someone, certainly with more experience than I could perhaps p[lease show me what I need to do to get this to work on my form.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `click` event for radio buttons instead of `onChange="showUser(this.value)"`.

```
<input type='radio' name='a' value='1' onClick="showUser(this.value)">
<input type='radio' name='a' value='2' onClick="showUser(this.value)">
<input type='radio' name='a' value='3' onClick="showUser(this.value)">
```

EDIT: The same name is used to make sure only one user can be selected.

That's it.
Comment if something is going wrong.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to help me out with this. It works a treat. Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Replace your dropdown list with this:

```
<input type="radio" name="users" onclick="showUser(this.value)" value="1" /> Peter Griffin<br />
<input type="radio" name="users" onclick="showUser(this.value)" value="2" /> Lois Griffin<br />
<input type="radio" name="users" onclick="showUser(this.value)" value="3" /> Glenn Quagmire<br />
<input type="radio" name="users" onclick="showUser(this.value)" value="4" /> Joseph Swanson<br />
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post. I've also tried this solution and again it works great. Kind regards